# How to pass a prop to a child component that is a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

Given:

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import WorkPlacePage from '../../components/welcome/WorkPlacePage';
import SkillPage from '../../components/welcome/SkillPage';

class Welcome extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    switch (props.match.params.welcomeId) {
      case "workplace":
        this.state = { step: 1 };
        break;
      case "skills":
        this.state = { step: 2 };
        break;
      default:
        this.state = { step: 1 };
        break;
    }
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  nextStep(props) {
    console.log('nextStep')
    console.log(this)
    this.setState({
      step : this.state.step + 1
    })
  }

  showStep(props) {
    const {history} = this.props

    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <WorkPlacePage history={history}
                              nextStep={this.nextStep} />
      case 2:
        return <SkillPage history={history}
                          nextStep={this.nextStep} />
      default:
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Case: Default</h1>
          </div>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    var style = {
      width : (this.state.step / 4 * 100) + '%'
    }
    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step">Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress" style={style}></progress>
        {this.showStep()}
      </main>
    )
  }
}



export default Welcome;
```

**WorkPlacePage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

class WorkPlacePage extends React.Component {

  saveAndContinue = (e) => {
    //e.preventDefault()
    this.props.nextStep()
  }

  render() {

    const history = createBrowserHistory();

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Workplace</h1>
        <span>
        survey things
        // <button onClick={() => history.push('/welcome/skills')}>next page</button>
        </span>

        <button onClick={() => this.saveAndContinue() }>XXX page</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WorkPlacePage;
```

When I click the button, I'm getting the error below for `this.props.nextStep()`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind `this` of the component to your function.

You can either use the ES6 fat arrow syntax:

```
saveAndContinue = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.props.nextStep()
}
```

Or you can bind it in the constructor function:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.saveAndContinue = this.saveAndContinue.bind(this);
}
```

Edit: To answer your remaining bugs:

Anytime you use `this.props` or `this.state` in a function you must ensure you are binding `this` from the component.

So in your `Welcome.js`, change your `nextStep` and `showStep` functions to use ES6 fat arrow syntax.

Regarding the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`, well it is because you are not passing the event to your function. So you will need to do the following change:

`<button onClick={() => this.saveAndContinue() }>XXX page</button>`

change to:

`<button onClick={ (e) => this.saveAndContinue(e) }>XXX page</button>`

Comment: Thanks, the ES6 version results on an error when I click the button: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

Comment: If I comment out `e.preventDefault()` saveAndContinue is calling nextStep() but then nextStep() is not undefined within w `this.state`

Comment: I just added in the nextStep() function, which is erring on `this.state` the console is saying it is undefined. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: You might have more binding issues. Can you edit your original post to include the full components?

Comment: updated to include full components. Does that help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to `bind` the context. Otherwise React can't identify it. Here I have changed the code in a way it works now.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WorkPlacePage from './WorkPlacePage'

class Welcome extends Component {
  nextStep() {
      console.log('Next Step callback is invoked !');
  }

  render(){
    return <WorkPlacePage nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)} />
  }
}

export default Welcome



import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class WorkPlacePage extends Component {
      saveAndContinue() {
        console.log('Invoking function passed from the parent');
        this.props.nextStep()
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={ this.saveAndContinue.bind(this) }>Save and Continue</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default WorkPlacePage
```

Hope this helps. happy coding !

Comment: This is incredibly helpful - Thank you!